# Can I use Inversion of Control with Android components such as Activities and Services?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, dagger

To facilitate cleaner testing, I would like to use Inversion of Control when developing my Android application. It looks straightforward to do with plain Java objects, but when I want to seed my `Activity`s and `Service`s with mock data, things start to look problematic as I don't have the ability to pass those component's dependencies to their constructor.

As an example, suppose I wanted to have my `Activity` use a real `HttpUrlConnection` during normal use, but for testing, I want to have it use a mock `HttpUrlConnection` that does not actually connect to the internet. Is there a way I could accomplish this through IoC for an `Activity`?

I realize there are dependency injection options such a Factories, and libraries such as Dagger that could help me out, but I was curious if there were other ways to accomplish this.

Comment: I realize there may be other things you want to stub, but for `HttpUrlConnection` you could use MockWebSever and feed your application local URLs. Another option would be to abstract the HTTP layer into an object which you can provide a fake implementation of.

Answer (score 2):

Since Constructor-Injection for Service or Activity is not possible in Android because these classes are instantiated with a parameterless constructor by the Android runtime you need some kind of **factory** that creates the external objects for you. To solve this I would create a Factory-Interface which can have a mock implementation like this:

```
public class MyService : Service {
   public static IFactory myFactory = new MyFactory(); 
             // the non-mocked version used as Default

   void myLocalFunction() {
     ...
     HttpUrlConnection connection = myFactory.createHttpUrlConnection();
     ... 
   }
}


public MyServiceTest : ... {
 class MyMockedFactory : MyFactory {
    HttpUrlConnection createHttpUrlConnection(){return new MockedHttpUrlConnection();}
 } 

 public myTest() {
  MyService.myFactory = new MyMockedFactory();
  .... do the test ...
 }
}
```